# C#: How to get initial value of variable?

Tags: c#

We have:

```cs
string helloWorld = "Hello world!";
void someVoid() {
  helloWorld += " additional value";
}
```

But it is necessary to access the initial value without creating an extra variable:

```cs
string helloWorld = "Hello world!";
string initialHelloWorld;
MyClass() { // Constructor
  initialHelloWorld = helloWorld;
}
void someVoid() {
  helloWorld += " additional text";
}
```

How can I do this? Sorry for not knowing well with C#

Comment: Can you explain what problem are you trying to resolve with _But it is necessary to access the initial value without creating an extra variable_?

Comment: Welcome to SO, @muyoneyo.. it's a little unclear what you're asking, so you might want to expand and what you want to achieve.  It's also worth noting that in C#, strings are *immutable*, that is - they cannot be modified; various string operations return a new, immutable, string as the result.  You might want to do a few C# tutorials!  Good luck.

Comment: I don't want to create an extra variable (`initialHelloWorld`) to store the initial value of the `helloWorld` variable.

Comment: Why you don't want to create another variable? What are you trying to solve with this? What is the problem?

Comment: @muyoneyo, as I said - strings are immutable, they can't change.

Comment: You shouldn't append information to it if you don't want the information. I am confused as to why there would ever be a case this is necessary. Perhaps you can do some non-intuitive pointer logic to retrieve the previous string (since they return new strings from @Moo-Juice comment). This seems like bad practice imo.

Comment: I have many such variables, and if I create a new extra variable for each one to store the initial value, it will not be good. There is, of course, a solution to use an array, but I would prefer to immediately get the initial value of a variable

Comment: I want use for Unity3D, example:
```csharp
Text textObj; /* value of textObj.text is "Score: " */
string initialTextObj;
int score;
void Start() {
  initialTextObj = textObj.text;
}

void Update() {
  textObj.text = initialTextObj + score;
}
```

Comment: @muyoneyo Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of what you want to do exactly. This sounds like an XY problem, which doesn't make any sense. If possible provide full, but short, source code which shows the problem you have and the problem you try to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it's a little unclear what you're asking, but I'm going to have a stab at it.

`string initial = "Hello World";  // Here is our initial value`

`string modified = initial + ", how are you doing?"; // Our modified value`

`modified` will contain the modified value (a new, concatenated string was returned - so I suppose it's incorrect to say it was strictly *modified*), but you still have access to `initial`, which will contain the original value.  I suspect you're trying to do something else, however and this is a bit of a testing-the-water question, and I'll update this answer if you can provide something more concrete.

**EDIT: Given your comment above, I think we can help**

So, you want a display string that has a value that can change, e.g. a score within a game.  In C# this can be achieved in multiple ways, and I'd normally suggest string interpolation, but not sure if Unity's flavour of C# supports that.

What we actually want to track, are two things...

`string template = "Your score is {0}";`

`int score = 5;`

To format this so it works, we just go:

`string result = string.Format(template, score);`

This will result in what you are wanting to achieve.

**EDIT 2: I highly suggest you pop out of Unity for a while and follow some C# tutorials to understand the language before jumping in to the world of games :)**

Comment: Perhaps he is looking for a reset function that resets the string back to the initial value? Atleast then he can store the string locally to the function (Provided he knows it...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I expected to see a shorter way, similar to this pseudocode: `string helloWorld = "Hello World"; helloWorld = "modified"; Console.Log(helloWorld.initial); /* Outputs "Hello World" */`

Comment: @muyoneyo Yeah, that won't happen, unless you explicitly wrote a change-tracking class around it.

Comment: @muyoneyo Or write your own string class!

Comment: As @Moo-Juice said, you can't do that without an additional variable.

Comment: I can also assume the interpolation of the text inside the Unity3D Editor, like: `Hello {world}`, but I not know how to do it. Could you suggest some free plugins for this?

Comment: @muyoneyo I'm not an expert on Unity, but I'm pretty sure what you're trying to achieve has been well documented, or available in a Unity tutorial.

Comment: Well, and thanks for all the answers! I will try to better search this in the documentation

Comment: @Moo-Juice `unless you explicitly wrote a change-tracking class around it` what about an implicit operator?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ, I find that would mask the intent a bit - It might just be me but I prefer verbosity and intent in methods, rather than the implicit/explicit implications - but of course, that's just me.